# Error in adding dependency in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am adding [this](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Paralloid/) library to my project. I followed the instructions. I put th project under app/lib. the problem is when i add :

```
compile project(':lib:paralloid:paralloid')
compile project(':lib:paralloid:paralloidviews')
```

an error message in generated:

> Error:(26, 0) Project with path ':lib:paralloid:paralloid' could not
>   be found in project ':app'.

Comment: Have look https://github.com/chrisjenx/Paralloid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you haven't specified `mavenCentral()` as a repository.
In build.gradle file, you need to specify which repository to use when resolving dependencies for building your project.
Add `mavenCentral()` repository in build.gradle file like this:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

And add library to your project

```
dependencies {
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx.paralloid:paralloid:0.1.+'
}
```

Comment: i just add mavenCentral() or i replace jcenter() by mavenCentral() ??

Comment: i added it under buildscript {
    repositories { and under allprojects {
    repositories { but it doesn't work !!

Comment: Looks like it is DEPRECATED, you need to follow the instructions mentioned and check the example files, they kept at https://github.com/chrisjenx/Paralloid

Comment: i clone the project and i tryed to open it on android studio. but it say that gradle home is missing !!!

Comment: While opening the project did you specified gradle home path?

Comment: no i opened it now but it ask for the github.exe directory !!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the other option they give?

```
dependencies {
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx.paralloid:paralloid:0.1.+'
}
```

Comment: yes i did. the result is:
Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: uk.co.chrisjenx.paralloid:paralloid:0.1.+

Comment: it's deprecated, try the example they propose and check it works